# How to move multiple commits from a branch to another branch

Tags: git, github

I have cut a branch X from master, then I did certain commits say,

```
  C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6
```

Now I want to merge X with master branch upto commit C2 and I would like to move commit C3 and C6 to different branch Y that I have cut from X. So what I want, look like following:

```
  master
    \
     \
      X-C1-C2-C3-C4-C5-C6
```

Finally it should be something like this:

```
    master------master
      \        /
       \      /
        X-C1-C2
              \
               Y-C3-C4-C5-C6
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers given are either very short or not quite doing what you asked for, so I will provide another one.

Let me start with the explanation that branches in git are merely references onto commits; they are literally a file containing the hash of the their commit. So there is close to no overhead when working with branches.

While you could create another branch `Y` it is not necessary. The easiest approach would be a simple merge from the `C2` commit into `master`.

```
git checkout master
git merge <hash-of-c2>
```

Note however that it's possible that this will result in a `fast-forward` merge. This will happen if there are no further commits on `master` so git just moves `master` to `C2`, if you want to force a merge commit and avoid a `fast-forward` you can use the `--no-ff` option when merging.

```
git merge --no-ff <hash-of-c2>
```

After you have done this your commit graph should look similar to this:

```
* (master) Merge commit
|\
| | * (X) C6
| | * C5
| | * C4
| | * C3
| |/
| * C2
| * C1
|/
* master commit
```

*(master) and (X) are the current commits of the branches.*

---

Obviously you can create multiple branches as you proposed. The easiest approach would be the following.

```
git branch Y X # Create Y branch which points at the same commit as X
git branch -f X <hash-of-c2> # Move X to point at C2
```

If there are any further questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: shouldn't your last command read:
`git branch -f X <hash-of-c2> # Move X to point at C2`

Answer (score 0):

You could create new branch Y from X. `reset` X back to the specified commit (C2). Then `merge` X into master.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most explicit way to accomplish what you're after:

```
git branch Y X
git checkout C2 # where "C2" is the commit hash of C2 commit - now Tip of X is at C2
git branch -f X # force repointing of X in .git/refs/heads/X
git checkout master
git merge X
```

Re @cabellicar123's answer:
I would prefer checkout over reset.  Reset will move HEAD, detach you from the `Y` branch, and  (effectively, they are always in the reflog) wipe out your C3-C6 commits.

Comment: Your approach would merge master "into" C2, op is asking for merging C2 into master.